# How do I access a dataframe which is the output of a function, outside the function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import openpyxl

import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox

from tkinter import *

from tkinter import messagebox

from tkinter import filedialog

from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename

from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, askopenfilename

 

def click():

    global df1

   

    window2=tk.Tk()

    window2.geometry("600x600")

    def open_file1():

        filetype1 = askopenfilename(filetypes =[("All files","*.*"),("CSV Files","*.csv"),("Excel files", "*.xlsx")])

        if(filetype1!=''):

            button2.configure(bg="green", fg="white")

            print("Upload finished successfully")

        else:

            button2.configure(bg="red", fg="white")

            print("No file uploaded")

 

        df1=pd.read_excel(filetype1)

        #print(df1)

   

    def open_file2():

        filetype2 = askopenfilename(filetypes =[("All files","*.*"),("CSV Files","*.csv"),("Excel files", "*.xlsx")])

        if(filetype2!=''):

            button3.configure(bg="green", fg="white")

            print("Upload finished successfully")

        else:

            button3.configure(bg="red", fg="white")

            print("No file uploaded")

        df2=pd.read_excel(filetype2) #, sheet_name=['Sheet1'], usecols=['Compiler Warnings'])

        #print(df2)    

 

    print(df1)   

    label2=tk.Label(window2, text = "Open the first file:").grid()

    button2 = tk.Button(window2, text = "Select first file", bg = "#ffffff" , width = 20, relief="raised", command=open_file1)

    button2.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=10)

   

    label3=tk.Label(window2, text = "Open the second file:").grid()

    button3 = tk.Button(window2, text = "Select second file", bg = "#ffffff" , width = 20, relief="raised", command=open_file2)

button3.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10)
button4 = tk.Button(window2, text = "Read", bg = "#ffffff" ,width = 20, relief="raised")
button4.grid(row=4, column=1) 

window2.mainloop() 

window=tk.Tk()

window.title("ReportCompare")

window.config(bg="#808080")

window.geometry('500x400')

label = tk.Label(window, text = "Report to be generated: ")

label.place(x=0, y=0)
label.grid()

button11 = tk.Button(window, text = "Errata Report", bg = "#ff8d85" , width = 20, relief="raised", command = click).grid(row=1, column=1)

 
button12 = tk.Button(window, text = "Compiler Warnings Report", bg = "#ff8d85" , width = 20, relief="raised", command=click).grid(row=3, column=1)

 

button13 = tk.Button(window, text = "Switch Compare Report", bg = "#ff8d85" ,width = 20, relief="raised", command=click).grid(row=5, column=1)

button14 = tk.Button(window, text = "Unused Messages Report", bg = "#ff8d85" ,width = 20, relief="raised", command=click).grid(row=7, column=1)

button15 = tk.Button(window, text = "Locked Object Report", bg = "#ff8d85" ,width = 20, relief="raised", command=click).grid(row=9, column=1)

 
window.mainloop()
```

I am trying to compare a column in file1 to a column in file2. For that I stored the excel in a dataframe. I’m trying to access the dataframe outside function open_file1(). But an error “df1 is not defined” is occurring. I tried declaring the variable as global but to not avail.
How can I access df1 and df2 outside their respective functions?

Comment: You need to copy the code as text, not as image.

Comment: Is window2 toplevel window?

Comment: Why same function twice when everything including file-type is same? Even if something changes, why can't it be passed as arguments to a single function?

Comment: function inside a function wont run directly unless it is called. Or is it an wrong indentation?

Answer (score 0):

Return the dataframes from your function(s) and use the returned values as needed. You also don't need two functions since they're both doing the same thing, just call the same function twice and store the returned dataframes as df1 and df2.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you may have to do. I couldn't check in real time as your code is not complete.

A single window in which the first two buttons for each file. And rest of the buttons for each report.

A single function for both the buttons viz., button1 and button2. Here the arguments are button(to specify it is for button1 or button2. The second argument is 0 or 1. Because the opened file is stored in a list files which can be called as and where required. These 0 or 1 is meant for denoting the index of the list. The 'uploaded' or 'Not Uploaded' message is popped up in the message box instead of printing.

Converting the excel file to dataframe is done by a separate function namely  data_frames(). This function takes the files from list and converts into dataframe.

Each report_generating button triggers a function for the respective report.(For  which you haven't written the code). Inside each of these functions, the function data_frames is called first so that the function can generate report from the dataframe.

df1 and df2 are declared as global in all these report generating functions

```
import tkinter as tk

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import openpyxl

import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox

from tkinter import *

from tkinter import messagebox

from tkinter import filedialog

from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename

from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, askopenfilename

files = []


def open_file(button, N):
    
    filetype = askopenfilename(filetypes =[("All files","*.*"),("CSV Files","*.csv"),("Excel files", "*.xlsx")])

    if(filetype != ''):
        files[N] = filetype

        button.configure(bg="green", fg="white")

        messagebox.showinfo('Success', "Upload finished successfully")

    else:

        button.configure(bg="red", fg="white")

        messagebox.showinfo('Failed', "Not Uploaded")


def data_frames():
    global df1, df2
    df1 = pd.read_excel(files[0])
    df2 = pd.read_excel(files[0])
    
    
def Errata_report():
    global df1, df2
    data_frames()
    #write function for Errata_Report
    
def Compiler_Warnings_Report():
    global df1, df2
    data_frames()
    #write function for Compiler_Warnings_Report
    
def Switch_Compare_Report():
    global df1, df2
    data_frames()
    #write function for  Switch_Compare_Report
    
def Unused_Messages_Report():
    global df1, df2
    data_frames()
    #write function for Unused_Messages_Report
    
def locked_Object_Report():
    global df1, df2
    data_frames()
    #write function for locked_Object_Report


window=tk.Tk()

window.title("ReportCompare")

window.config(bg="#808080")

window.geometry('500x400')
    
label = tk.Label(window, text = "Report to be generated: ")

label.place(x=0, y=0)
label.grid()



button1 = tk.Button(window, text = "Open first File", bg = "#ff8d85" , width = 20, relief="raised", command = lambda x, y :open_file(button1, 0))
button1.grid(row=1, column=1)



button2 = tk.Button(window, text = "Open Second File", bg = "#ff8d85" , width = 20, relief="raised", command = lambda x :open_file(button2, 1))
buuton2.grid(row=3, column=1)

button11 = tk.Button(window, text = "Errata Report", bg = "#ff8d85" , width = 20, relief="raised", command = Errata_report
button11.grid(row=5, column=1)

 
button12 = tk.Button(window, text = "Compiler Warnings Report", bg = "#ff8d85" , width = 20, relief="raised", command=Compiler_Warnings_Report)
button12.grid(row=7, column=1)

 

button13 = tk.Button(window, text = "Switch Compare Report", bg = "#ff8d85" ,width = 20, relief="raised", command=Switch_Compare_Report)
button13.grid(row=9, column=1)

button14 = tk.Button(window, text = "Unused Messages Report", bg = "#ff8d85" ,width = 20, relief="raised", command=Unused_Messages_Report)
button14.grid(row=11, column=1)

button15 = tk.Button(window, text = "Locked Object Report", bg = "#ff8d85" ,width = 20, relief="raised", command=locked_Object_Report)
button15.grid(row=13, column=1)

 
window.mainloop()
```